# In Lubuntu, how can I make the default-theme scroll bars thicker?

Tags: lubuntu, gui, lxde, scrollbar

I use Lubuntu 17.04 (zesty). I'm somewhat annoyed by how the window scroll bars are super-thin, and I often miss them or take too much time to press them.

Is there a (reasonably simple) way to make them somewhat wider (in the default theme)?

Comment: Have you tried other themes?

Comment: @DKBose: Not really, I'm pretty satisfied with the default theme. See edit. But I'll also try that as a workaround.